# mvc : i want to set textBox value from property1 or property2 if property1 is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to do something like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PackagePrice.MotherCompanyPercentage??model.DefaultMotherCompanyRevenuePercentage , new {id = "txtMotherCompanyPercentage", type = "number" , Class = "form-control"})
```

Comment: Please make your question clearer.

Comment: The set the value of `MotherCompanyPercentage` to the value of `DefaultMotherCompanyRevenuePercentage` in the controller if its `null`

Comment: i mean i want to set textbox Value with DefaultMotherCompanyRevenuePercentage if MotherCompanyPercentage is null

Comment: I know, You need to set the value in the GET method before you pass it to the view (you cannot use the code you have shown)

Comment: its already set but how to use it in the view this is the trick

Comment: Your not understanding! In your GET method, set the value of property `MotherCompanyPercentage` to the value of `DefaultMotherCompanyRevenuePercentage` if its `null` and just use `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PackagePrice.MotherCompanyPercentage)`